# How to apply Simplify only to elements of list that cause specific Warning

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, symbolic

I have a set of replacement rules I use to analytically compute nested integrals of very long symbolic expressions since `Integrate` literally takes forever. To do that I use `List@@` to transform a sum into a list of summands and apply my rules to each element of the list `list`. An example that causes problems at later evaluation is e.g.

```
list = {Cos[x], Sin[x], -( Cos[t3 (d1 - d2)]/(1728 tg^3 (d1 - d2)^2)) + Cos[t3 (d1 - d2)]/(864 tg^3 (d1 - d2) (-d1 + d2)) +  Cos[t3 (d1 - d2)]/(864 tg^3 (d1 - d2) (2 (d1 - d2) - 2 (-d1 + d2))) -  Cos[t3 (d1 - d2)]/(864 tg^3 (d1 - d2) (2 (d1 - d2) + 2 (-d1 + d2))) + Cos[3 t3 (d1 - d2)]/(1728 tg^3 (d1- d2)^2) - Cos[t3 (d1 - d2) - 2 t3 (-d1 + d2)]/(864 tg^3 (d1 - d2) (2 (d1- d2) - 2 (-d1 + d2))) - Cos[t3 (d1 - d2) + 2 t3 (-d1 + d2)]/(864 tg^3 (d1 - d2) (-d1 + d2)) +  Cos[3 t3 (d1 - d2) + 2 t3 (-d1 + d2)]/(864 tg^3 (d1 - d2) (2 (d1 - d2) + 2 (-d1 + d2))) + (t3 Sin[t3 (d1 - d2)])/(432 tg^3 (d1 - d2))};
```

For later computation I do for instance need `list[[3]] /. {d1 -> 0.045, d2 -> -0.35}` which will evaluate to `Indeterminate` since there is a `1/0` component inside due to the way the previous replacement rules work. But observe that

```
(Simplify@list[[3]]) /. {d1 -> 0.045, d2 -> -0.35}
```

works fine and yields the correct result (compared to `Integrate` result for that specific element), since the terms causing `ComplexInfinity` in fact cancel out. Note that I cannot include `Simplify` in my replacement rules because there are only few terms having that particular problem, simplifying the rest is not necessary and takes forever as well.

My goal is to perform a check, e.g. apply the replacement `{d1 -> 0.045, d2 -> -0.35}` to my list `list`, look for `Indeterminate` warning and only apply `Simplify` to those terms that cause the warning. The simplified terms should still depend on `d1,d2` so the replacement of those should only be used to find critical list elements.

How can this be achieved at all? In principle, I would prefer a solution where you would directly apply `Simplify` if the warning is recognized to avoid multiple calls of the list. However, since I am clueless on how to do it at all I will be happy with any solution, anyway.

**Edit** To avoid misunderstandings: For this example, `Simplify` yields a result almost instantly. That is not the case for my full set of lists/terms. There seems to be no chance to `Simplify` the list - even with appropriate assumptions - in reasonable timescales.

**Edit 2** As pointed out in a comment below, Szabolcs' suggestion to Map a function like `checkInt[expr_, rule_] := Quiet[Check[expr /. rule, Simplify[expr]]];` over `list` did indeed work (i) at all and (ii) in reasonable time. Compared to trying to simplify the whole list - which has not even finished after multiple days - I was now able to achieve what I want in roughly 35 minutes.

Comment: `Map` this?  `f[expr_] := Module[{result},
  result = expr /. rules;
  If[result == Indeterminate, result = Simplify[expr] /. rules];
  result]`.  Or this?  `Check[# /. rules, Simplify[#] /. rules] &`.  `Check` can check for specific messages only and `Quiet` can silence them.

Comment: You may be interested in this [rule based integrator](http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~arich/) too.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for your fast reply. In fact, `Map[f,list]` does not work since it seems that the `Indeterminate` case is not recognized properly. However, your second suggestion using `Check` works perfectly fine! If you post it as an answer, I can accept. Also, many thanks for pointing to RUBI which may definitely be of interest for me :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not exactly what you asked about, but did you try this:

```
  list = {Cos[x], 
   Sin[x], -(Cos[t3 (d1 - d2)]/(1728 tg^3 (d1 - d2)^2)) + 
    Cos[t3 (d1 - d2)]/(864 tg^3 (d1 - d2) (-d1 + d2)) + 
    Cos[t3 (d1 - d2)]/(864 tg^3 (d1 - d2) (2 (d1 - d2) - 
         2 (-d1 + d2))) - 
    Cos[t3 (d1 - d2)]/(864 tg^3 (d1 - d2) (2 (d1 - d2) + 
         2 (-d1 + d2))) + 
    Cos[3 t3 (d1 - d2)]/(1728 tg^3 (d1 - d2)^2) - 
    Cos[t3 (d1 - d2) - 
       2 t3 (-d1 + d2)]/(864 tg^3 (d1 - d2) (2 (d1 - d2) - 
         2 (-d1 + d2))) - 
    Cos[t3 (d1 - d2) + 
       2 t3 (-d1 + d2)]/(864 tg^3 (d1 - d2) (-d1 + d2)) + 
    Cos[3 t3 (d1 - d2) + 
       2 t3 (-d1 + d2)]/(864 tg^3 (d1 - d2) (2 (d1 - d2) + 
         2 (-d1 + d2))) + (t3 Sin[
        t3 (d1 - d2)])/(432 tg^3 (d1 - d2))};
```

Then

```
 AbsoluteTiming[(Simplify /@ list)]

(*   {0., {Cos[x], 
  Sin[x], -((
   Sin[(d1 - d2) t3] (4 (-d1 + d2) t3 + Sin[2 (d1 - d2) t3]))/(
   1728 (d1 - d2)^2 tg^3))}}   *)
```

As we see, it takes three times nothing, at list within this example. And this:

```
  AbsoluteTiming[(Simplify /@ list) /. {d1 -> 0.045, d2 -> -0.35}]

(*  {0., {Cos[x], 
  Sin[x], -((0.00370904 Sin[0.395 t3] (-1.58 t3 + Sin[0.79 t3]))/
   tg^3)}}   *)
```

takes four times nothing.

Have fun!

Comment: In fact, for this particular example `Simplify` yields a result instantly. However, the actual terms I deal with are way more complicated and the lists have around 400.000 elements where each element is way more comlicated than what is shown in the question. I have been running `Simplify` naively with appropriate assumptions for 4 days now, without end in sight. But anyways, thanks for your contribution :)

Comment: If you map `Simplify ` onto your list and it takes much time, than the same is to be expected, if you map the combination `Simplify[ReplaceAll[#, {d1 -> 0.045, d2 -> -0.35}]]& `. Clearly that not the terms like `Sin[x] `or `Cos[x] `give rise to such a timing. This may be the indication that there are terms (those creating your problems) that are much too complex themselves.

Comment: Indeed. And this is why I only want to `Simplify` those few terms that cause trouble if you map `ReplaceAll[#,{d1->0.045,d2->-0.35}]` or any other values of `d1,d2`. Purely replacing does not take that much time, so first checking for warning and only simplifying if a warning occurs (few cases) should not take that much time, I hope. Edit: Basically, there are only `Cos,Sin` terms involved with lots of different arguments and (longish) prefactors depending on more symbols than shown here. That is why `Simplify` probably takes so long... Just my guess